# how to turn jwt settings into simplejwt settings?

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Here is my problem. I have a project that used rest_framework_JWT like this

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    "JWT_VERIFY": True,
    "JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION": True,
    "JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA": datetime.timedelta(days=30),
    "JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX": "Bearer",
    "JWT_AUTH_COOKIE": "x-access-token",
}
```

but now i want to change from JWT to rest_framework_simpleJWT, what is the corresponding fields should i change to in simplejwt? Is this right?

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=5),
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_X_ACCESS_TOKEN',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add and change the settings in the `INSTALLED_APPS` and `REST_FRAMEWORK.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`.

In settings.py file,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework_simplejwt'
]

...

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': {
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes, I've already did that, but how i change JWT_AUTH field to SIMPLE_JWT field, like there is no cookie field in simplejwt, should i do it manually

Comment: Just remove all the settings for `JWT_AUTH` and follow the instructions in the documentation from the simple jwt.

Comment: The documentation is here as you know. https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html

Comment: yes, I've read the doc but kinda confused, like JWT_VERIFY" is what field in simplejwt

Comment: You feel confused because you think you're switching. Just think you didn't know about jwt, and you're implementing simple jwt from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample configuration settings you can set:

```py
# Django project settings.py

from datetime import timedelta
...

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

Link to its documentation is here: [documentation](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html)

Also, this is a boiler plate code that you can also plug and play in your project for Django authentication with simplejwt.
You can simply clone it and add above configuration in settings.py file there.

[Boiler plate code for django simplejwt authentication](https://github.com/rishabbahal9/DJANGO-JWT-AUTHENTICATION)